# bsts 0.5.1/ 0.6.5 package installation is failing on R 3.2.5 even after installing all dependencies?

Tags: r, c++11, install.packages

Specifications:

OS: SLES 11 SP3
R: 3.2.5 
BH: 1.65.0-1
Boom: 0.7
BoomSpikeSlab: 0.9.0 
xts: 0.10-1 
zoo: 1.8-1
bsts: 0.5.1
gcc: gcc 4.3 was installed for R 3.2.5 installation. Also, for Boom 0.7 "SystemRequirements: GNU Make, C++11" I installed gcc 7.2.0 in my first attempt and gcc 4.8 in my second.

Makeconf:

```
    C_VISIBILITY = -fvisibility=hidden 
    CC = gcc -std=gnu99 
    CFLAGS = -g -O2 $(LTO)  
    CPICFLAGS = -fpic 
    CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include 
    CXX = g++ 
    CXXCPP = $(CXX) -E 
    CXXFLAGS = -g -O2 $(LTO) 
    CXXPICFLAGS = -fpic 
    CXX1X = g++ 
    CXX1XFLAGS =  -g -O2 $(LTO) 
    CXX1XPICFLAGS = -fpic 
    CXX1XSTD = -std=gnu++11 
    DYLIB_EXT = .so 
    DYLIB_LD = $(CC) 
    DYLIB_LDFLAGS = -shared -fopenmp# $(CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS) 
    DYLIB_LINK = $(DYLIB_LD) $(DYLIB_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) 
    ECHO = echo 
    ECHO_C = 
    ECHO_N = -n 
    ECHO_T = 
    FC = gfortran 
    FCFLAGS = -g -O2 $(LTO) 
    FCLIBS = 
    F77 = gfortran 
    F77_VISIBILITY = -fvisibility=hidden 
    FFLAGS = -g -O2 $(LTO) 
    FLIBS =  -lgfortran -lm 
    FCPICFLAGS = -fpic 
    FPICFLAGS = -fpic 
    FOUNDATION_CPPFLAGS = 
    FOUNDATION_LIBS = 
    JAR = 
    JAVA = 
    JAVAC = 
    JAVAH = 
    JAVA_HOME = 
    JAVA_CPPFLAGS = 
    JAVA_LIBS = 
    JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH = 
    LAPACK_LIBS = -L\$(R_HOME)/lib\$(R_ARCH) -lRlapack 
    LIBINTL= 
    LIBM = -lm 
    LIBR0 = -L\$(R_HOME)/lib\$(R_ARCH) 
    LIBR1 = -lR 
    LIBR = -L\$(R_HOME)/lib\$(R_ARCH) -lR 
    LIBS =  -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lrt -ldl -lm 
    LIBnn = lib64 
    LIBTOOL = $(SHELL) "\$(R_HOME)/bin/libtool" 
    LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib64 
    LTO = 
    MAIN_LD = $(CC) 
    MAIN_LDFLAGS = -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp 
    MAIN_LINK = $(MAIN_LD) $(MAIN_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) 
    MKINSTALLDIRS = $(R_HOME)/bin/mkinstalldirs 
    OBJC = 
    OBJCFLAGS =  $(LTO) 
    OBJC_LIBS = 
    OBJCXX = 
    R_ARCH = 
    RANLIB = ranlib 
    SAFE_FFLAGS = -g -O2 -ffloat-store 
    SED = /bin/sed 
    SHELL = /bin/sh 
    SHLIB_CFLAGS = 
    SHLIB_CXXFLAGS = 
    SHLIB_CXXLD = $(CXX) 
    SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS = -shared 
    SHLIB_CXX1XLD = $(CXX1X) $(CXX1XSTD) 
    SHLIB_CXX1XLDFLAGS = -shared 
    SHLIB_EXT = .so 
    SHLIB_FCLD = $(FC) 
    SHLIB_FCLDFLAGS = -shared 
    SHLIB_FFLAGS = 
    SHLIB_LD = $(CC) 
    SHLIB_LDFLAGS = -shared# $(CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS) 
    SHLIB_LIBADD = 
    SHLIB_LINK = $(SHLIB_LD) $(SHLIB_LDFLAGS) $(LIBR0) $(LDFLAGS) 
    SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS = -fopenmp 
    SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS = -fopenmp 
    SHLIB_OPENMP_FCFLAGS = 
    SHLIB_OPENMP_FFLAGS = 
    STRIP_LIBS = strip --strip-unneeded 
    STRIP_STATIC_LIBS = strip --strip-debug 
    TCLTK_CPPFLAGS = 
    TCLTK_LIBS = 
    YACC = bison -y 
    STATIC_LIBR = # -Wl,--whole-archive "\$(R_HOME)/lib\$(R_ARCH)/libR.a" -Wl,--no-whole-archive $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)  $(LIBINTL)  $(LIBS) 
    R_XTRA_CFLAGS = 
    R_XTRA_CPPFLAGS =  -I\$(R_INCLUDE_DIR) -DNDEBUG 
    R_XTRA_CXXFLAGS = 
    R_XTRA_FFLAGS = 
    ALL_CFLAGS = $(R_XTRA_CFLAGS) $(PKG_CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) 
    ALL_CPPFLAGS = $(R_XTRA_CPPFLAGS) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CLINK_CPPFLAGS) 
    ALL_CXXFLAGS = $(R_XTRA_CXXFLAGS) $(PKG_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) 
    ALL_OBJCFLAGS = $(PKG_OBJCFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_CFLAGS) $(OBJCFLAGS) 
    ALL_OBJCXXFLAGS = $(PKG_OBJCXXFLAGS) $(CXXPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_CXXFLAGS) $(OBJCXXFLAGS) 
    ALL_FFLAGS = $(R_XTRA_FFLAGS) $(PKG_FFLAGS) $(FPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_FFLAGS) $(FFLAGS) 
    ALL_LIBS = $(PKG_LIBS) $(SHLIB_LIBADD) $(LIBR)# $(LIBINTL) 

    .SUFFIXES: 
    .SUFFIXES: .c .cc .cpp .d .f .f90 .f95 .m .mm .M .o 

    .c.o: 
            $(CC) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 
    .c.d: 
            @echo "making $@ from $<" 
            @\$(CC) -MM $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $< > $@ 
    .m.d: 
            @echo > $@ 
    .cc.o: 
            $(CXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 
    .cpp.o: 
            $(CXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 
    .cc.d: 
            @echo "making $@ from $<" 
            @\$(CXX) -M $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $< > $@ 
    .cpp.d: 
            @echo "making $@ from $<" 
            @\$(CXX) -M $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $< > $@ 
    .m.o: 
            $(OBJC) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_OBJCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 
    .mm.o: 
            $(OBJCXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_OBJCXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 
    .M.o: 
            $(OBJCXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_OBJCXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 
    .f.o: 
            $(F77) $(ALL_FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 
    .f95.o: 
            $(FC) $(PKG_FCFLAGS) $(FCPICFLAGS) $(FCFLAGS) -c  $< -o $@ 
    .f90.o: 
            $(FC) $(PKG_FCFLAGS) $(FCPICFLAGS) $(FCFLAGS) -c  $< -o $@
```

Problem:

Even after installing all the prerequisites, bsts installation is failing.
  I also tried installing later versions of bsts which are compatible with R 3.2.5 but no luck with them too.

```
    **Error Message:**

    **Error bsts_0.5.1:**

    t-325-test:/var/opt/teradata/packages/R/R_packages # R CMD INSTALL bsts_0.5.1.tar.gz
    * installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib64/R/library’
    * installing *source* package ‘bsts’ ...
    ** package ‘bsts’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** libs
    g++ -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I /usr/local/lib64/R/bin/Rscript -e cat(system.file(package='Boom')) /include -DNO_BOOST_THREAD DNO_BOOST_FILESYSTEM -DADD_ -DR_NO_REMAP -DRLANGUAGE -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include" -I"/usr/local/lib64/R/library/BH/include"   -fpic  -g -O2   -c aggregate_time_series.cc -o aggregate_time_series.o
    aggregate_time_series.cc:8:10: fatal error: LinAlg/Types.hpp: No such file or directory
     #include "LinAlg/Types.hpp"

    compilation terminated.
    make: *** [aggregate_time_series.o] Error 1
    ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘bsts’ removing ‘/usr/local/lib64/R/library/bsts’

    =================================================================

    **Error bsts_0.6.5:**

    t-325-test:/var/opt/teradata/packages/R/R_packages # R CMD INSTALL bsts_0.6.5.tar.gz
    * installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib64/R/library’
    * installing *source* package ‘bsts’ ...
    ** package ‘bsts’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** libs
    g++ -std=gnu++11  -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/lib64/R/bin/Rscript -e cat(system.file(package='Boom'))/include -DNO_BOOST_THREADS -DNO_BOOST_FILESYSTEM -DADD_ -DR_NO_REMAP -DRLANGUAGE -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include" -I"/usr/local/lib64/R/library/BH/include"   -fpic   -g -O2   -c aggregate_time_series.cc -o aggregate_time_series.o
    In file included from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/Models/DataTypes.hpp:33:0,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/Models/CategoricalData.hpp:22,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/r_interface/boom_r_tools.hpp:30,
                     from aggregate_time_series.cc:9:
    /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/cpputil/Ptr.hpp:128:33: warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         template <class Y> Ptr(std::auto_ptr<Y> &rhs): pt(rhs){}

    In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
                     from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/locale:43,
                     from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/iomanip:43,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/cpputil/report_error.hpp:22,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/LinAlg/Array.hpp:29,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/r_interface/boom_r_tools.hpp:28,
                     from aggregate_time_series.cc:9:
    /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:51:28: note: declared here
       template<typename> class auto_ptr;

    In file included from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/Models/DataTypes.hpp:33:0,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/Models/CategoricalData.hpp:22,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/r_interface/boom_r_tools.hpp:30,
                     from aggregate_time_series.cc:9:
    /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/cpputil/Ptr.hpp:142:32: warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         Ptr & operator=(const std::auto_ptr<Y> &rhs){

    In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
                     from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/locale:43,
                     from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/iomanip:43,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/cpputil/report_error.hpp:22,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/LinAlg/Array.hpp:29,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/r_interface/boom_r_tools.hpp:28,
                     from aggregate_time_series.cc:9:
    /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:51:28: note: declared here
       template<typename> class auto_ptr;

    g++ -std=gnu++11  -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I /usr/local/lib64/R/bin/Rscript -e "cat(system.file(package='Boom'))/include -DNO_BOOST_THREADS -DNO_BOOST_FILESYSTEM -DADD_ -DR_NO_REMAP -DRLANGUAGE -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include" -I"/usr/local/lib64/R/library/BH/include"   -fpic   -g -O2   -c bsts.cc -o bsts.o
    In file included from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/Models/DataTypes.hpp:33:0,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/Models/CategoricalData.hpp:22,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/r_interface/boom_r_tools.hpp:30,
                     from utils.h:7,
                     from bsts.cc:3:
    /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/cpputil/Ptr.hpp:128:33: warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         template <class Y> Ptr(std::auto_ptr<Y> &rhs): pt(rhs){}

    In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
                     from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/locale:43,
                     from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/iomanip:43,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/cpputil/report_error.hpp:22,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/LinAlg/Array.hpp:29,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/r_interface/boom_r_tools.hpp:28,
                     from utils.h:7,
                     from bsts.cc:3:
    /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:51:28: note: declared here
       template<typename> class auto_ptr;

    In file included from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/Models/DataTypes.hpp:33:0,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/Models/CategoricalData.hpp:22,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/r_interface/boom_r_tools.hpp:30,
                     from utils.h:7,
                     from bsts.cc:3:
    /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/cpputil/Ptr.hpp:142:32: warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         Ptr & operator=(const std::auto_ptr<Y> &rhs){

    In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
                     from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/locale:43,
                     from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/iomanip:43,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/cpputil/report_error.hpp:22,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/LinAlg/Array.hpp:29,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/r_interface/boom_r_tools.hpp:28,
                     from utils.h:7,
                     from bsts.cc:3:
    /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:51:28: note: declared here
       template<typename> class auto_ptr;

    g++ -std=gnu++11  -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/lib64/R/bin/Rscript -e "cat(system.file(package='Boom'))" /include -DNO_BOOST_THREADS -DNO_BOOST_FILESYSTEM -DADD_ -DR_NO_REMAP -DRLANGUAGE -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include" -I"/usr/local/lib64/R/library/BH/include"   -fpic   -g -O2   -c mixed_frequency.cc -o mixed_frequency.o
    In file included from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/Models/DataTypes.hpp:33:0,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/Models/CategoricalData.hpp:22,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/r_interface/boom_r_tools.hpp:30,
                     from mixed_frequency.cc:6:
    /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/cpputil/Ptr.hpp:128:33: warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         template <class Y> Ptr(std::auto_ptr<Y> &rhs): pt(rhs){}

    In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
                     from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/locale:43,
                     from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/iomanip:43,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/cpputil/report_error.hpp:22,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/LinAlg/Array.hpp:29,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/r_interface/boom_r_tools.hpp:28,
                     from mixed_frequency.cc:6:
    /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:51:28: note: declared here
       template<typename> class auto_ptr;

    In file included from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/Models/DataTypes.hpp:33:0,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/Models/CategoricalData.hpp:22,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/r_interface/boom_r_tools.hpp:30,
                     from mixed_frequency.cc:6:
    /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/cpputil/Ptr.hpp:142:32: warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         Ptr & operator=(const std::auto_ptr<Y> &rhs){

    In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
                     from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/locale:43,
                     from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/iomanip:43,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/cpputil/report_error.hpp:22,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/LinAlg/Array.hpp:29,
                     from /usr/local/lib64/R/library/Boom/include/r_interface/boom_r_tools.hpp:28,
                     from mixed_frequency.cc:6:
    /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:51:28: note: declared here
       template<typename> class auto_ptr;

    mixed_frequency.cc: In function ‘void {anonymous}::TranscribeResponseData(BOOM::Ptr<BOOM::AggregatedStateSpaceRegression>, BOOM::Ptr<BOOM::StateSpaceModel>, BOOM::RErrorReporter*)’:
    mixed_frequency.cc:262:66: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::vector<BOOM::Ptr<BOOM::UnivData<double>, true>, std::allocator<BOOM::Ptr<BOOM::UnivData<double>, true> > >&’ from expression of type ‘BOOM::IID_DataPolicy<BOOM::StateSpace::MultiplexedDoubleData>::DatasetType {aka std::vector<BOOM::Ptr<BOOM::StateSpace::MultiplexedDoubleData, true>, std::allocator<BOOM::Ptr<BOOM::StateSpace::MultiplexedDoubleData, true> > >}’
       std::vector<Ptr<BOOM::DoubleData> > & data(augmented_model->dat());
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
    make: *** [mixed_frequency.o] Error 1
    ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘bsts’
    * removing ‘/usr/local/lib64/R/library/bsts’
```

What is the reason for the failure shown?
Also, what is the earliest GCC version needed to build the library? 
Also, Is there possibly a compiled bsts package available?